# user is not authorized to perform: ce:GetCostAndUsage

Tags: boto3, amazon-iam

I am using boto3, trying out Cost Exploer to get cost and usage

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ce')
client.get_cost_and_usage()
```

Already grant the following permissioin to the user

```
  "aws-portal:ViewUsage",
  "aws-portal:ViewBilling"
```

But always get error

*An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetCostAndUsage operation: User: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/User1 is not authorized to perform: ce:GetCostAndUsage on resource: arn:aws:ce:us-east-1:123456789*

Answer (score 18):

Just found answer from here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-example-policies.html#example-policy-ce-api

**Example 11: View costs and usage**

To allow IAM users to use the AWS Cost Explorer API, use the following policy to grant them access:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ce:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I realised you can't choose individual resources for "ce" actions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-example-policies.html, see first paragraph

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find existing small scope read-only policy to get usage statistics.

Creating new policy through the web "Visual Editor" is easy too:

1. Navigate to IAM -> Policies -> Create Policy
2. Select service as `Cost Explorer Service`
3. Tick `[X] Read` permissions
4. Click Review
5. Name it, for example `MyCostExplorerRead`
6. Assign the newly created policy to your user

Comment: Wow, this saved me hours of debugging. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to add [X] LIST permissions too!!!